MSSQLで特定文字が含まれる場合、違う値が同一扱いされる
テーブル生成する際に以下のように対象のテーブルのCollationを定義しています。
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

（英語の大文字と小文字は同一扱いし、日本語以外の使われるサービスのため）
テーブル統合の作業のため、PKにプレフィックスを付けるUPDATEの実施結果、重複キーエラーになりました。
調べた結果、PKが'11'のレコードと、'ーー'のレコードは別々のものとして扱われますが、例えば'1'をプレフィックスを付ける場合、'111'と'1ーー'が同じ値として扱われることが判明しました。（ヽもーと同じ現象）
'ー'や'ヽ'の関連の処理を行っても、重複キーエラーになるので、その他の文字もここに該当すると思います。
エラーログではどこが重複になるレコードか判断できない状態です。（'11'とどのレコードが重複の状態なのかが見極めないです）
COLLATEを_BINでバイナリで指定する場合、この問題は解決しますが、大小文字が別々のレコードのなるため、この方法は使えない状態です。
ひらがなか、カタカナを前に付けると別途のデータとして認識してくれますが、原因の対象を全部把握していないため、解決策が見当たらないです。
恐れ入りますが何かご教授いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。
※以下は検証のため、実行してみたテストです。
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.unicode_string_test
CREATE TABLE dbo.unicode_string_test (
   string NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
)
-- 1 : U+0031
-- 2 : U+0032
-- ー : U+30FC
-- ヽ : U+30FD
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'111'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'11ー'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'11ヽ'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'1ーー'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'1ヽヽ'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'ーーー'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'222'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'22ー'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'22ヽ'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'2ーー'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'2ヽヽ'
INSERT dbo.unicode_string_test SELECT N'ヽヽヽ'

SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'111'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'11ー'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'1ーー'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'1ーヽ'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'ーーー'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'222'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'22ヽ'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'2ヽヽ'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'2ーヽ'
SELECT * FROM dbo.unicode_string_test WHERE string = N'ヽヽヽ'


SQL_で始まるSQL Server照合順序はSQL Server 2000より前との互換のために残されているもので、

SQL Server 照合順序は旧バージョンとの互換性を維持するためにサポートされていますが、新規の開発作業に使用しないでください。

と案内されています。この照合順序は当時そのような挙動をしていたと受け入れ、その挙動について今さら意味を見出そうとするべきではありません。
Windows照合順序の中から適切なものを選択するようにしてください。以下のクエリで一覧を取得できます。
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE [name] NOT LIKE N'SQL%';


質問内容の修正、ご回答ありがとうございます。Latin1_General_CP1_CI_ASに設定しても同じ問題が発生するため、他の対応をためしてみます

@AselKim Invalid collation 'Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'. になるだけだと思います。ともあれ、質問文に書かれたことに答えるので、きちんと適切なCOLLATEを使用して質問してください。
